# Opencart: Different price per country or zone?

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

Can i have different price in each product based on the country of a registered customer? (im talking about the base price, not shipping or tax or special price)

Any ideas or any module to suggest?

Comment: Well, how do you plan to distinguish the traffic commng from each country ?
Will you look up your visitor's IP address ? Will you require to login first in order to get their country ? Do you plan to change the price as soon as they login ? Do you want to display a splash screen first to select their country of origin ?

Comment: Is there a module for any of the cases that you mentioned? lets say that i will change the price when they login. but if a solution exists for any of the other cases, give me some instructions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your users are registered already, with an actual billing or shipping address, you could easily change the pricing according to the user's country.

There are 3 ways you can approach it. Since I am assuming you are familiar with how to customize OpenCart I will layout the guidelines with minimal code. I am also assuming all your users are already registered as you suggested.
The options are:

1. Customer Groups (Easy but not recommended).
2. Adding a price ratio column to the countries table. (Moderate but recommended).
3. Override your currencies (Easy but limited solution).

**Use Customer Groups.**

You will have to create a unique customer group for each country (or continent if you wish) and upon signup you will assign the correct customer group to the user. You can do it automatically by changing your registration model and controller files or manually by making sure that all new customers need to be approved first.
When setting a product discount, you can set up a different discount for each customer group.
This is A LOT OF WORK and will BE HARD to maintain but it’s possible.

*Note that, by default, customers will be able to see the base price before discount (which can sometimes be lower than their customer group price). You can edit the product.tpl or your css file and remove it from showing.*

**Add a price_ratio column**

The 2nd way (my recommended way) will be to modify your country mysql table and add a fixed price ratio for each country (i.e US is 1, UK is 1.2, Thailand, 0.8 etc). This will change base pricing for all products in a fixed ratio.

1. Edit database table 'country' and add column named 'price_ratio'.
2. Edit your model and controller files to calculate the effective price by price * price_ratio.
3. Send it to the view and show the effective price.
4. You will also need to modify your admin localization/country model, view and controller so you can make changes to the price_ratio directly from the Admin.

With this method, you only need to change the price_ratio once and all prices will be updated (in contrary to the first method where you’ll have to change pricing for each product and each country).

*Also, technically if you are lazy about it, you could store all price ratios in an associative array in your code and avoid all other modifications, but that would be harder to modify down the road.*

**Use Currencies**

3rd way will be to override your currencies but that would only give you limited control (i.e different countries in Europe share the same currency so you can not display different pricing).

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is a good practice here on SO that if You are copying somebody's answer (or it's part) You mention that, or You just do not copy at all but point to that answer that has same/similar *thoughts as You* ... You then do not just look like a jerk...

Answer (score 1):

There is no such extension, AFAIK, and asking for recommending of such an extension is a reason for closing Your question. But it is possible to implement it these ways:

1. check the IP address - find out the country of origin (via one of many free/paid services out there on the internet) and change the prices accordingly. This may not be 100% accurate as users may use proxies and thus user from USA may have IP from China in the end...
2. require users to log in first and then check their shipping/invoice address to get the country. This may also have some hacks considering the user may have more shipping addresses (to different countries) or his shipping and invoice address's country may be different
3. inform users that the prices are country-dependent and that they to pick up one country (a select box similar to language/currency chooser) where the shipping will be done and after this You can change the prices accordingly. Then there will have to be a check whether the selected country is the same as the country of shipping/invoice address...

Anyway, all methods will require a huge modification - maybe a new module for backend to set the product/country price ratio (similar to the currency) or a modification of product details to be able to set a concrete price for each country (keep in mind there are hundreds of countries so maybe it would be wise to allow just few of them) and of course a modification for frontend to calculate the prices correctly in regards to the country...

My opinion: this is useless waste of time... You can achieve similar behaviour when using ratios for different currencies (different country - different currency - until you want to set different prices for EU countries with EUR)...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of extension i have found related to your problem

1. Assign Customer Group By IP  (By D3MO)
2. Auto Price Increment / Reduction Rules By GeoIP (By D3MO)

There is another extension to set different prices for each currency

1. Currency Price (By ashwani_multi )

I hope these will help you. Following are the links for these extensions

1. https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=34652&filter_search=Customer%20Group%20Price
2. https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=29023
3. https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=34754&filter_search=Customer%20Group%20Price